# I'm having issues linking to a header in the same document with CommonMark, Markdig, MAUI, and Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: maui, markup, commonmark, markdig

Here is an excerpt from my Markdown text.

```
This window is divided into 5 regions -
[*Naming Fields*](#namingfields),
...
Each region is described in more detail below.

<a name="namingfields"></a>
### Naming Fields
```

Here is my C# code to convert from Markdown to HTML:

```
var result = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(text);
```

And here is the resulting HTML.

```
<p>This window is divided into 5 regions -
<a href="#namingfields"><em>Naming Fields</em></a>,
...
Each region is described in more detail below.</p>
<p><a name="namingfields"></a></p>
<h3>Naming Fields</h3>
```

I get the same behavior using this Markup.

```
<a id="namingfields"></a>
```

That is, using `id` in place of `name`.

The strange behavior I'm seeing is that when I set a breakpoint to examine `result` as HTML, I can click the "Naming Fields" link, and I get the desired behavior - focus moves to the target header.  However, when I continue from my breakpoint, and click the link in the context of the running application, I get the following error: `Can't reach the webpage at https://appdir/#namingfields`.

I'm using the MAUI WebView control, and I have verified that BaseUrl is null. I have also inspected the HTML in the WebView control, and it is unchanged from what I see in the debugger. But obviously, my link is being redirected, and I don't understand why.  I would appreciate any insights anyone has to offer.

And by the way, isn't there a way I can use Markup, instead of embedded HTML, to specify the `"namingfields"` target?

Thanks.
Chuck

---- Updated post ----

In response to @GuangyuBai-MSFT's request for the demo, here are the relevant files.

```
HelpPage.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="AzureResourceNaming.HelpPage"
             >
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
        <WebView Source="{Binding HelpViewSource}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>


HelpPage.xaml.cs:
using Markdig;

namespace AzureResourceNaming;

public partial class HelpPage : ContentPage
{
    private HtmlWebViewSource _helpViewSource = new();
    public HtmlWebViewSource HelpViewSource
    {
        get { return _helpViewSource; }
        set
        {
            if (_helpViewSource != value)
            {
                _helpViewSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HelpViewSource));
            }
        }
    }

    public HelpPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Content != null)
        {
            Content.BindingContext = this;
        }

        var text = LoadMarkdownContent().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var result = Markdown.ToHtml(text);
        var viewSource = new HtmlWebViewSource
        {
            Html = result,
            BaseUrl = string.Empty
        };
        HelpViewSource = viewSource;
    }

    private static async Task<string> LoadMarkdownContent()
    {
        using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("HelpFile.txt");
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return contents;
    }
}
```

HelpFile.txt is shown at the top of the post.  I launch the HelpText view with the following:

```
   var helpWindow = new Window(new HelpPage())
   {
       Width = 850,
       Height = 700
   };
   Application.Current?.OpenWindow(helpWindow);
```

---- More information ----

I added an event handler, `WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)`, which does get triggered when I click on the link in my HelpText document.  Upon examining `sender.Source`, I see that it is properly set to the `HtmlWebViewSource` I created in the constructor.  However, `e.Source` is set to a `UrlWebViewSource` object I don't recognize, but it's `Url` property is set to `https://appdir/#namingfields` which I do recognize as the target mentioned in the error message.

I then added a second event handler, `WebView_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` which gets triggered when I launch the HelpPage view, and `sender.Source` is once again set to the `HtmlWebViewSource` I created in the constructor.  Unfortunately, `EventArgs` is just an empty base class, and holds no interesting information, and `BindingContextChangedEventArgs` is not defined for MAUI applications.  So, I don't know, but it is highly likely, that this event was triggered by initially setting `WebView.Source`.

So, at this point, I now know that I'm getting an erroneous navigation event, but I don't know where it's coming from or why.

---- Even More information ----

Upon exploring the stack trace upon triggering `BindingContextChanged` I now know that the triggering event was `Content.BindingContext = this;` and this has nothing to do with setting `WebView.Source`.

Upon exploring the stack trace upon triggering `WebView_Navigating` I was unable to find any useful information.

---- Conclusive Information ----

To close the loop on possibilities, I modified my `HelpPressed` code as follows:

```
using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("HelpFile.txt");
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
var result = Markdown.ToHtml(text);

var targetFile = "...";  
using var outputStream = File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
await streamWriter.WriteAsync(result);

var xyz = await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(targetFile));
```

Instead of passing the html string into a WebView control for display, I save it in a file, then launch a browser to display it.  This works just fine - all the links work as expected.  So, this clearly points the finger at a bug in the WebView control, and not at Markdown or Markdig.

Comment: Did you use the WebView to displays the HTML files? Can you provide the demo, and I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I have modified the original post to provide a complete code sample to reproduce the problem.